# How to remove duplicates entries, sum them and assign to a new vector?

Tags: c++, tuples

I have a `std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, double> triplets` that is sorted by the first term of the tuple. It looks like

```
triplets = {
{0, 0, 1}, 
{1, 2, 5}, 
{2, 2, 1}, 
{2, 2, 3}, 
{3, 0, 2}, 
{4, 4, 2}, 
{4, 4, 5}, 
{5, 5, 6}
}
```

I need to remove the duplicates tuples that have the same first and second entries, keep just one entry related to these duplicates and sum the third entries.

The expected result must be

```
triplets_new = {
{0, 0, 1}, 
{1, 2, 5}, 
{2, 2, 4}, 
{3, 0, 2}, 
{4, 4, 7}, 
{5, 5, 6}
}
```

Is there a way to do that using STL or a for-like solution?

Comment: Using the standard library functions exclusively (with no looping) might make more work than you may otherwise require. I suggest you first try to write _any_ solution. See the "Possible Implementation" section of [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) documentation, if you don't know the basics of how to remove duplicates from a vector. You can extend that by adding your extra criteria where you accumulate the third value.

Comment: You'll find that many computer problems can be solved exactly the same way you'd solve them if you had a pen, some paper, and someone calling out inputs. If you work out how you would solve the problem and start there, you probably won't be too far away from a working solution that you can then analyze for patterns you can exploit to improve the efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sorted, loop through vector and check each element if it has same first and second value with the next element.If so, add the third value to this element and remove the next element.

If not sorted, build an hash table and make {first,second} as key.
loop through your vector, if key already exist, add the third to current value in the hash table, otherwise add it to the hash table. Last step is loop through the hash table and convert it back to a vector.